# Принудительный вызов события в javascript часть номер 2 Заставить код сработать

Tags: javascript

Вот такой код, заставляет сторонние скрипты и события срабатывать, но не всегда это работает, есть что нибудь лучше этого?

```js
<body onload="dosmth()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function dosmth() {
 <script src="......</script>
}
</script>
```

Comment: есть еще какие принудительные запуски в javascript языке?

Comment: если честно, то этот код буксует,  грузится грузится и не может запустить другое событие, страница как бы реагирует на процессы, но ,.. чет процесс не запускается, или может дело в стороннем скрипте, который вмонтирован в тело рабочего скрипта

Comment: Скрипт уже загружен на страницу? Зачем вы его загружаете в другом скрипте? Вам нужно чтобы сработало какое то конкретное событие навешанное на элемент из другого скрипта?

Comment: да, именно так, чтобы заставить другой скрипт сработать, как это правильно сделать? его не надо вставлять в тело скрипта который будет запускать событие? привидите пример например какой нибудь "левый скрипт" который нужно запустить с помощью   вот этого <script type="text/javascript"> 
function funonload() {

} 
window.onload = funonload;
</script>

Comment: Парни, я попозже подойду, я ушел на кухню позже отпишусь.

Comment: Если вы знаете элемент на который навешано событие и самое событие - берем jquery и вызываем $( "#foo" ).trigger( "click");  Подробнее тут - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Если нужен pure js, вам сюда - https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events

Comment: Спасибо, можно привести какой рибудь пример пусть и с вымышленным скриптом, который например нужно запустить автоматически через  javascript, сторонний скрипт нужно вмонтировать в тело  javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о браузере вот так можно.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function funonload() {
   //
} 
window.onload = funonload;
</script>
```

От объекта window, будет вызываться всегда

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно дать пинка скрипту сторонней системы.

Comment: сейчас туда скрипт вставлю вместо линка, попробую спасибо

Comment: неочоень понимаю, в чем проблема. Даже если скрипт сторонний его загрузка просто должна быть раньше, чем вызов window.onload.

Comment: Парни, я попозже подойду, я ушел на кухню позже отпишусь.